# Change text width without increasing the stack width

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]

```
  let months = ["january" , "februarry", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august",    "september", "october", "november", "december"]
   var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                VStack {
                    if month == "october" {
                        Text(month)
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I display the text in its full length without changing the width of the VStack and thus the distance between the squares.

It should look like this:

[image: It should look like this]

Answer (score 0):

not clear what you are asking here, but have you tried something like this:

```
let months = ["january" , "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack {
            ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                VStack {
                    Text(month).fixedSize()  // <--- this
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 25, height: 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post with a picture showing with how it should look like

Answer (score 0):

ok, how about this hack then:

```
let months = ["january" , "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]
@State var chosenMonth = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(chosenMonth)
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack {
            ForEach(self.months, id: \.self) { month in
                Rectangle().frame(width: 25, height: 10).onAppear(perform: {
                    if month == "october" {
                        self.chosenMonth = month
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Now without hard-code completely (and added animation for demo)

[image: demo]

```
                if month == self.selectedMonth {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .alignmentGuide(.monthAlignment, computeValue: { d in
                            if month == self.months.first {
                                return d[.leading]
                            } else if month == self.months.last {
                                return d[.trailing]
                            } else {
                                return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                            }
                        })
                } else {
                    Rectangle()
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 10)   // << here !!
        }
    }
}
.padding()
.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: selectedMonth)
```

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestDynamicSelectionAlignment.swift)

#### Original

Here is possible approach based on alignment guides. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

The idea is to use bars & text on different layers and align them using custom alignment guide, with handling corner cases to not allow text fall out of screen.

[image: demo]

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum MonthAlignment : AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
        }
    }
    
    static let monthAlignment = HorizontalAlignment(MonthAlignment.self)
}

struct DemoMonthAlignment: View {
    let months = ["january" , "februarry", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]
    @State private var selectedMonth = "october"
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(alignment: .monthAlignment, spacing: 2) {
            Text(selectedMonth)
                .alignmentGuide(.monthAlignment, computeValue: { d in
                    if self.selectedMonth == self.months.first {
                        return d[.leading]
                    } else if self.selectedMonth == self.months.last {
                        return d[.trailing]
                    } else {
                        return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                    }
                })
            HStack {
                ForEach(months, id: \.self) { month in
                    Group {
                        if month == self.selectedMonth {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                .alignmentGuide(.monthAlignment, computeValue: { d in
                                    if month == self.months.first {
                                        return d[.leading]
                                    } else if month == self.months.last {
                                        return d[.trailing]
                                    } else {
                                        return d[HorizontalAlignment.center]
                                    }
                                })
                        } else {
                            Rectangle()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```